# Is it possible to integrate streamlit-lightweight-charts into an html page using flask?

Tags: python, html, flask, charts, streamlit

https://github.com/freyastreamlit/streamlit-lightweight-charts Please tell me how I can (if I can) place such a chart on an html page with custom data using flask?

It is assumed that the page will have 6-12 charts of this type https://freyastreamlit-streamlit-lightw-examplespricevolumechart-j8ldyo.streamlit.app/

It starts up strange somehow. I tried to integrate it through the sys module, but I still didn’t understand how to place this thing on the HTML page